# Altering a part of a URL programatically to suit specific Purpose

Tags: c#, .net, string, url

I have the URL `https://test-wonder.test.local/attributes/testdata`  stored as

```
string url="https://test-wonder.test.local/attributes/testdata";
```

due to  a problem of accessibility I need to modify this url to in order to use it. and I have to do this programtcally to something in the form of `https://test-wonder.wondercloud.com/attributes/testdata`

From what I have tried so far `string.Replace()` does work to a certain extent but is the only way of doing this is using `string.Replace()` or is there a better way of doing it.

Also is it possible to break down parts of this URL . Say for example if I want to break down the part "`testdata`" or "`attributes`" is there a way to do so and maybe store it as a certain variable.

Comment: You can use : string url=string.Format("https://{0}/attributes/testdata";folder);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to dynamically change your hostname you can use string interpolation, which on C# 6 and newer can be written as:

```
string hostname = GetHostnameValue(); // replace this with the method to get your hostname value. For example, from a config file.
string url = $"https://{hostname}/attributes/testdata";
```

To break up the URL, look into the Uri class [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=netframework-4.8). Example:

```
Uri u = new Uri(url);
var segments = u.Segments;
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed 
Thanks !